What colour notations does Plotly.js support?
I'm trying to plot a bar chart, with bars of a specific colour, using Plotly 1.47.4:
Plotly.newPlot(plotElement,
               [{
                   type: "bar",
                   x: ["A", "B", "C"],
                   y: [1, 2, 3],
                   marker: {color: "red"}
               }]);

For the marker colour, i can use named CSS colours, and traditional CSS #rrggbb notation, and more modern CSS rgb(r g b) and hsl(h s% l%) notation. But modern CSS oklch(l% c h) and hwb(h w% b%) don't seem to work - i get default blue bars.
If i inspect the generated SVG, i see what however i specify the colour in the newPlot call, the path element constituting the bar has a fill colour defined in rgb(r, g, b)  format.
So, it seems Plotly is parsing the marker colour value, and translating it to RGB itself.
What notations does Plotly support here? Is there a plan to support the newer ones?

The documentation about marker.color doesn't say much :

It accepts either a specific color or an array
of numbers that are mapped to the colorscale relative to the max and
min values of the array or relative to marker.cmin and marker.cmax
if set.

But marker.colorscale is more explicit about which notation is supported :

The colorscale must be an array containing arrays mapping a normalized
value to an

rgb,
rgba,
hex
hsl,
hsv,
or a named color

string.

I don't know if there is any plan to support other notations, but I guess the right place to check/ask is on github, @see plotly/plotly.js.
